# IOS problem with click on popup menu in nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, nuxt.js

There is a menu on the site. For mobile it is with full width and height. On android devices, it works great, but when using the menu on an iPhone (safari), the menu starts to behave strangely and causes clicks under the menu to work.

If there is nothing under the menu item, it works fine. But if there is some button or link under the menu item, then it does not count the menu item, and sometimes a click works under it

here is vue component:

```
<div class="header-content-catalog">
  <button v-click-outside="hideCategories" class="btn btn-warning" @click="toggleCategories(), showFirstRecommend()">
    <i class="icofont-navigation-menu" />
    <span>
      catalog
    </span>
  </button>
  <div :class="[{ 'show-categories': showCategories }, 'header-content-catalog-modal']">
    <div class="catalog-modal-dismiss">
      X
    </div>
    <div class="catalog-modal-list">
      <ul>
        <li
          v-for="item in categories"
          :key="item.id"
          :class="[{hovering: item.id === +$route.params.id}, 'catalog-modal-list-item']">
          <nuxt-link :to="`/mebel/${item.id}`" @click.stop>
            {{ item.name }}
          </nuxt-link>

          <!-- this is a recommended product, displayed on the desktop, on mobile devices the block is hidden -->
          <div v-if="item.recommended_product_id != 0" class="catalog-modal-list-item_recommended category-content__item">
            <h5>Recommended products</h5>
            <div class="card-wrapper">
              <nuxt-link :to="'/mebel/product/' + item.recommended_product_id" @click.stop>
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem; height: auto;">
                  <div class="card-img-wrap">
                    <nuxt-img format="webp" :src="api_url + `uploads/` + item.product_photos[0]" class="card-img-top" :alt="item.product_name" loading="lazy" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-stars">
                      <client-only>
                        <star-rating
                          :rating="+item.rating"
                          :rounded-corners="true"
                          :border-width="1"
                          :star-size="20"
                          :read-only="true"
                          :show-rating="false"
                          class="mb-2"
                        />
                      </client-only>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-available">
                      in stock
                    </div>
                    <h5 v-if="item.price > 0" class="card-title">
                      {{ item.price_from ? 'from' : '' }} {{ item.product_price }}$
                    </h5>
                    <p class="card-text">
                      {{ item.product_name }}
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </nuxt-link>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

vue component here:

```
<!-- directive for click outside - close menu -->

directives: {
    ClickOutside
},
data () {
    return {
      isHovering: false,
      showCategories: false
    }
},
methods: {
    hideCategories () {
      this.showCategories = false
      const body = document.querySelector('body')
      body.style.overflow = 'visible'
    },
    toggleCategories () {
      this.showCategories = !this.showCategories
      const body = document.querySelector('body')
      if (this.showCategories) {
        body.style.overflow = 'hidden'
      } else {
        body.style.overflow = 'visible'
      }
    },
    showFirstRecommend () {
      const listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.catalog-modal-list-item')
      let isHovering = false
      for (const item of listItems) {
        isHovering = item.classList.contains('hovering')
        if (item.classList.contains('hovering')) {
          isHovering = true
          break
        }
      }
      if (!isHovering) {
        document.querySelector('.catalog-modal-list-item').classList.add('hovering')
      }
    },
    handleHoverCategories () {
      const catalogItems = document.querySelectorAll('.catalog-modal-list-item')
      for (const item of catalogItems) {
        item.onmouseover = function () {
          const listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.catalog-modal-list-item')
          for (const item of listItems) {
            item.classList.remove('hovering')
          }
          this.classList.add('hovering')
        }
        item.onmouseleave = function () {
          let hovered = document.querySelectorAll('.hovering')
          let clearHover = true
          
          hovered = document.querySelectorAll('.hovering')
    
          if (hovered.length === 0) {
            clearHover = false
          }
    
          if (!clearHover) {
            this.classList.remove('hovering')
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

css here:

```
.header-content-catalog {
    position: relative;
    button {
      padding: 10px 20px;
    }
    &-modal {
      position: absolute;
      overflow: hidden;
      max-height: 0;
      top: 50px;
      left: 0;
      background-color: #e8e8e8;
      color: black;
      padding: 0;
      border-radius: 10px;
      box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px 0px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.2);
      transition: 0.2s all ease-in-out;
      z-index: 100;
      -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
      touch-action: none;
      -ms-touch-action: none;
      .catalog-modal-dismiss {
        margin: 5px 20px 15px 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-weight: 800;
        display: none;
        justify-content: flex-end;
      }
      ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding-left: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        position: relative;
        min-width: 570px;
        min-height: 450px;
        li {
          font-size: 14px;
          font-weight: 700;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          display: flex;
          & > a {
            display: block;
            padding: 10px 30px;
          }
          &.hovering {
            color: #7845d1;
            background-color: #fff;
            & .catalog-modal-list-item_recommended {
              display: block;
            }
          }
          & .catalog-modal-list-item_recommended {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            padding: 15px 40px;
            height: 100%;
            border-radius: 15px;
            background-color: #fff;
            color: #212121;
            font-weight: 500;
            h5 {
              color: #212121;
              text-transform: none;
            }
            & img {
              width: 100%;
              height: 100%;
              object-fit: cover;
            }
            .card {
              &-img-wrap {
                height: 220px;
                overflow: hidden;
                img {
                  height: 100%;
                  width: 100%;
                  object-fit: cover;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      &.show-categories {
        max-height: 500px;
        padding: 10px 0;
      }
    }
  }
  
/* show modal(popup) on mobile */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .header-content-catalog {
        &-modal {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            left: 0;
            overflow: scroll;
            &.show-categories {
              max-height: 100vh;
            }
            .catalog-modal-dismiss {
                display: flex;
            }
        }
    }
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
    .header-content-catalog-modal {
        ul {
            min-width: auto!important;
            min-height: auto!important;
        }
        /* hide recommended block */
        .catalog-modal-list-item_recommended {
            display: none!important;
        }
    }
}
```

```
@media (max-width: 575px) {
    .header-content-catalog-modal {
        ul {
            min-width: auto!important;
            min-height: auto!important;
        }
        /* hide recommended block */
        .catalog-modal-list-item_recommended {
            display: none!important;
        }
    }
}
```

see working site: https://mebelvsem-dnr.ru/

There are no special ideas, as you can see in the code, there have been attempts to use properties such as:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
touch-action: none;
-ms-touch-action: none;
```

But it did not help

Comment: same problem with https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

the problem is when you click (touch) element event `touch(start|end|move)` triggers, but you do not do anything with this event, try to call `stopPropagation()` is should solves the problem

```
<v-list-item
                            class="search-item v-list-item--link"
                            @touchstart="onTouch($event)"
                            @touchend="onTouch($event)"
                            @touchmove="onTouch($event)"
                        >
                            <v-list-item-avatar v-if="!!data.item.image">
                                <v-img :src="data.item.image"></v-img>
                            </v-list-item-avatar>
                            <v-list-item-content class="search-item-content">
                                <v-list-item-title v-html="data.item.title" />
                                <v-list-item-subtitle
                                    v-if="!!data.item.barcode"
                                    v-html="data.item.barcode"
                                />
                            </v-list-item-content>
                        </v-list-item>
```

and function

```
methods: {
        onTouch(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
        },
}
```